# TypeError Python String Format

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to print a header but this is the error I keep getting: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting. This is my code:

```
print("%10s$20s%20s \n" % ("Year", "Data Breaches", "Records Exposed"))
```

Thanks

Comment: It looks like a typo. Your second substitution has `$` not `%`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo - replace `$` with `%` (5th character)